# Error of compilation when I open p5 on my computer

Tags: javascript, p5.js

When I want to open the p5 file on my computer, it tells me an error.  Can you help me to solve it? Thank you.

The file that I think there is an error:

[image: file]

The error:

[image: error]

Comment: Please make sure your example is a [Minimal, Verifiable and Complete Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You may also want to look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help writing a good question. This is not the type of question that belongs on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the p5.js file inside a zip file which is causing the error. It's not ideal to view and modify files within a zip.

You can simply fix this by moving the p5.js file out of the zip file. You can use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) to move the file outside or use the Windows version.